# Change HTML element class from PHP form on a different page - Custom CMS

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system

Is it posible to change the class of a 'li' or other html element from a form/drop down menu on a different page?

Any ideas?

Example:

Back-end form:

```
 Image 1
 Image 2
 Image 3
 none - selected
```

Front-end html file:

```
<li id="image1" class"hide"> </li>
<li id="image2" class"hide"> </li>
<li id="image3" class"hide"> </li>
```

---

Back-end form (option selected):

```
 Image 1 - selected
 Image 2
 Image 3
```

Front-end html file:

```
 <li id="image1" class"show"> </li>
 <li id="image2" class"hide"> </li>
 <li id="image3" class"hide"> </li>
```

---

### Css

```
.hide {
display: none;
}

.show {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your html is invalid... cant you use the value stored as the selected image to determine which class to add?

Comment: The html is only an example... It's within a jQuery slider if that helps

Comment: No it dont help, how do you store which value is selected from the `Back-end form`?

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that... probably through a MySQL database?

Comment: u should use jquery or js function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, sure. It depends on what exactly you're trying to do with it. Since you tagged `php`, I'll go with that, but you could also use JavaScript if it doesn't need to be permanent.

What you'd probably want to do is have all the paths to your images stored in a database alongside meta information; for the sake of simplicity we'll just go with your `class` and an `id`:

```
ID   IMAGE                  CLASS
1    'images/image1.png'    hide
2    'images/image2.png'    hide
N    'images/imageN.png'    hide
```

From there you could echo out the class for each element rather than hardcoding it, probably with a `foreach`:

```
<image class='<?= $imageClass ?>' src='<?= $imageSrc ?>' />
```

Then your drop down for an image might look something like this:

```
<form method='post' action='action.php'>
    <select name='<?= $imageID ?>'>
        <option value='show'>Show</option>
        <option value='hide'>Hide</option>
    </select>

    <button type='submit'>Change class</button>
</form>
```

Which would send the selection off to `action.php`. That file, in turn, will update `images`, perhaps with an SQL query:

```
$query = "UPDATE images SET class = :imageClass WHERE id = :imageID";
```

Then you can use the script to header the browser back to whichever page you need to in order to allow the settings to take place without refreshing the browser.

Unfortunately, the question was a bit vague, so I can't help much more than that without writing a much longer post. Hopefully this gives you an idea of how it could work.